# Homepage got manipulated

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, homepage

I just opened SO and wondered that homepage was totally messed up. Here is a look at it:

[image]

Its not happening now. I would like to know that why it happened and is not happening now?

*<sub>Chrome 76 / Windows 10 <sub>64 bit</sub></sub>*

Comment: Did you try a hard refresh of the page? It's the kind of issue that tends to happen occasionally on any website. And might persist due to caching. A hard refresh tends to clear these up the majority of the time - if it persists afterwards, *then* it might be an actual site issue. Although it's still about equally likely to be a problem on your end due to an addon or maybe router/firewall/something else that blocks the CSS download.

Answer (score 7):

This looks like part of the style or a script wasn't loaded by your browser.  The extra text at the top left is from the "Products" menu, and several of the other things in the top bar are not formatted or displaying properly.

This is likely just a transient failure caused by a lost packet somewhere.

Comment: That's exactly how it looks like when [stacks.css](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css) is disabled (or not loaded) For a forced repro `$('[href*="stacks.css"]')[0].disabled = true`. Now, that doesn't explain why it didn't load, this would require OP to check their Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

[shouldiblamecaching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com)

Just clear cache and refresh the page.
It occurred because of connection error after some parts of the page were loaded.